# How to match earliest and latest start times and print them out along with their corresponding details?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I need to print the earliest and latest start times for each user along with their corresponding information using awk. I am not allowed to use sort. If there is a tie for the latest or earliest start time, then take the one with the UID that comes first alphabetically.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
BEGIN { }
{
   if( $5 <= $5 ) {
     lateTime = $5;
   }
   else {
     earlyTime = $5;
   }
END {
    print("Earliest Start Time:", $1, $2, $3, $4, earlyTime, $5, $6, $7);
    print("Latest Start Time:", $1, $2, $3, $4, lateTine, $5, $6, $7);
}
```

I have tried to compare the 5th field with itself as its iterating through, but I'm having trouble with the logic of it all. Any help is appreciated.

I am given this text file.

```
UID   PID  PPID C STIME TTY    TIME     CMD
adz110 5344 5334 0 08:47 pts/2  00:00:00 bash
dmq292 6908 6854 0 08:53 pts/1  00:00:00 bash
adz110 7227 7150 0 08:54 pts/9  00:00:00 who
erg474 7466 7461 0 08:54 pts/10 00:00:00 ls
dmq292 7966 7960 0 08:55 pts/13 00:00:00 assign1 . sh if of
xle135 8636 8628 0 08:58 pts/15 00:00:00 bash
xle135 8983 8636 0 08:59 pts/15 00:00:00 ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
zeh458 9057 1980 0 08:59 pts/7  00:00:00 vim prog . c
```

and it needs to look like this afterwards:

```
Earliest Start Time:
adz110 5344 5334 0 08:47 pts/2 00:00:00 bash
Latest Start Time:
xle135 8983 8636 0 08:59 pts/15 00:00:00 ssh ctf.cs.utsarr.net
```

Comment: @Tiw sorry, about that. I edited the post.

Comment: I'm assuming the spaces inside `ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net` are editing error, If not so please tell me.

Comment: When you say `for each user` you actually mean `across all users`, right? Is your input always already sorted by time and then uid as shown in your example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'FNR==1{next} FNR==2{timeE=timeL=$5;lineE=lineL=$0;} timeE>$5{lineE=$0;timeE=$5} timeL<$5{lineL=$0;timeL=$5} END{print "Earliest Start Time:\n" lineE "\nLatest Start Time:\n" lineL}' file
```

Put in multiple lines for readability:

```
awk '
FNR==1{next}
FNR==2{
    timeE=timeL=$5;
    lineE=lineL=$0;
} 

timeE>$5{
    lineE=$0;
    timeE=$5
} 

timeL<$5{
    lineL=$0;
    timeL=$5
} 

END{
    print "Earliest Start Time:\n" lineE "\nLatest Start Time:\n" lineL
}' file
```

Comment: Could you please message me when you have a chance? I have a question about implementing this into the rest of my program. I'm new to the website and not really sure how to message you myself. Thank you.

Comment: @OldLettuce  What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Given the input you provided all you need is:

```
$ awk 'FNR==2{beg=$0} !seen[$5]++{end=$0} END{print "Earliest" ORS beg ORS "Latest" ORS end}' file
Earliest
adz110 5344 5334 0 08:47 pts/2  00:00:00 bash
Latest
xle135 8983 8636 0 08:59 pts/15 00:00:00 ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
```

If that's not adequate then update your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output.